# return json object using servlet

Tags: jquery, json, jsp, servlets

I've got a servlet. It works like this - I send action-name, servlet create action-object, perform some tasks in action, then return string `view` as result - to what page I should send user. Servlet works the same for `doGET` and for `doPost`.

```
    String name = getActionName(req);

    Action action = (Action) pico.getComponentInstance(name);

    String view = action.exec(req, resp);
    // router
    if (view.startsWith("redirect:")) {
        resp.sendRedirect(view.substring("redirect:".length(),
                view.length()));
    } else {
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                "/" + view + ".jsp").forward(req, resp);
    }
```

I've got AjaxAction where I get value from request, get object from database, transform it into json string. But how to return it from action? Action returns string, represents next page where user should be sent. I send him to `main` page.

```
    String requestId = req.getParameter("requestId");
    Long id = Long.valueOf(requestId);
    Request item = requestDao.read(id); 
    String json = "";
    json = new Gson().toJson(item);

    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    try {
        resp.getWriter().write(json);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "main";
```

I send request for JSON object every time I change value in `<select>`(with `id = "re"`).

```
   $("#re").change(function() {
        var $id = $('#re').val();
        $.get('AjaxAction.do', {
            requestId : $id
        }, function(respJSON) {
                            alert(respJSON);
            $.each(respJson, function(key, value) {
                $('#' + key).val(value);
            });
        });
    });
```

But neither `alert` appear nor value in #+key change. So it seems function doesn't work.
So how properly return JSON object from Action?
I debugger `AjaxAction` creates object and `return "main";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change `return "main";` to `return null;`
2. After that you will be able to get ajax response and alert() on the same page;
3. Instead of alert you can redirect user to another page now if needed by doing `document.location="anotherpage";`