# Get servlet value in javascript and assign that value to a textbox using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

I am having a servlet where I am getting value from properties file. I want to get the value from servlet in my javascript and set that value to a textbox using AJAX. I am totally new to Ajax so please provide me a solution by looking at my code.

**SERVLET**

```
       @WebServlet("/PopulateProperties")
      public class PopulateProperties extends HttpServlet {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     Properties prop = new Properties(); 
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String serverName=request.getParameter("servernameDD");
    List<Map<String,String>> returnObj = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    String[] servers = getSearchAttr("servers");
    if (servers != null && servers.length > 0) {


        String[] lookfor = getSearchAttr("servers_lookfor");
        for (String server : servers) {
            Map<String,String> obj = new HashMap<String,String>();
            if (lookfor != null) {
                for (String look : lookfor) {
                    //System.out.println("looking for :"+look);
                    String value =  prop.getProperty(server+"_"+look);
                    if(server.equalsIgnoreCase(serverName)){
                        if(look.equalsIgnoreCase("Links")){
                        String getlook=prop.getProperty(look);
                        String getlink=prop.getProperty(server+'_'+look,"Links");
                        System.out.println("Hello" +getlink);
                        System.out.println(getlook);
                        request.setAttribute("serverLink", getlink);

                        }
                    }
                    if (value != null) {
                        obj.put(look, value);
                    }
                    request.setAttribute("servers", server);
                    request.setAttribute("lookfor", look);

                }           

            }       
            //System.out.println("Object :"+obj);
            returnObj.add(obj);

        }


    }
    response.sendRedirect("updateserverstatus.html");

        }






private String[] getSearchAttr( String property){
    String lookfor = prop.getProperty(property,"");
    String[] ret = {lookfor};
    if (lookfor.contains(",")) {
        return lookfor.split(",");
    } else {
        //System.out.println("comma not present in "+property);
        //System.out.println("webservice :"+lookfor);
        return ret;

        }

     }
```

I tried the following Ajax request but I am getting "serverLink undefined error"

```
function OnSelectionChange(){


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/PopulateProperties",
    data: "{Links: " + serverLink + "}",
    success: function(result){
        alert(result.d);
        console.log(result);
    }
});
  }
```

Comment: serverLink is not declared anywhere .it is undefined ..

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt I am trying to get serverLink from servlet

Comment: Your approach is wrong.. First your AJAX request will hit the URL with data you provide it and when servlet returns it will go to the success function of your AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

You use a servlet to get data and forward. It is not a proper way to provide data with servlet. A better solution is:

In your servlet, you should just return the properties data in a json format. You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956800/return-json-object-using-servlet)
Then you get this data with ajax in your html page, and update the text of textarea.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to crerate separate servlet just for this purpose.  This will keep your code coherent. 
Pass all the parameter which will be used to narrow down to the data you need to retrive.

For simplicity just return the value or you can return the data as a JSON key value pair.

If your textbox is like this. `<input type="text" id="prop_txt">`
then the ajax code will be

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/PopulateProperties",
  data: "{A:(..a value..),
          B:(..b value..),
          ....
          ....
          (..all the parameters required..)
         }",
  success: function(result){
      //alert(result.d);
      console.log(result);
      $('#prop_txt').val(result);
  }
});
```

Hope this heplps.

Comment: You have the servlet . right? You must be knowing what values are needed to retrive the data needed to be populated in that textbox..

Comment: Fetched from request?? you are not fetching it at all. Try `request.getParameter('Links')`

Comment: You can retrieve the values, obtained from the servlet, only in the success function block.. Not like that what you are writing in data..

Comment: @Vaishnavi You are setting the attribute serverLink in that servlet which is you are going to call through ajax .. return that from servlet like out.print(servlet) link and get in the success function result variable.

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt.. did you mean like this `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  out.println(serverLink);`

Comment: Still I am not getting that in my  ajax. I am getting error :(

`$.ajax({
  
    type: "POST",
    url: "/PopulateProperties",
    data: "serverlink : serverLink",
   success: function(result){
        alert(result.d);
        console.log(result);
        $('#serverlink').val(result); 
  alert("success");
 },
 error:  function(data, status, er){
        alert(data+"_"+status+"_"+er);
    }

 
  
  });`